# How to test a method called inside the component instance using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

how do we test (spy) inner function of an instance here `this.props.onSave()` using Jest.

```
class AddImage extends Component {  

   constructor(props) {
    this.onContinue = this.onContinue.bind(this);
   }

   onContinue() {
     this.props.onSave(img)
       .then(()=>{
          //redirect to some url
        });
   }
}
```

**onContinue** is called on click of a button.

test file code -

```
describe('AddImage', () => {
 beforeAll(() => {
    const enzymeWrapper = ShallowRender(<AddImage {...props} />);
    onContinueSpy = jest.spyOn(enzymeWrapper.instance(),'onContinue');
    // how to spy onSave
  });

  it('should continue and save image',()=>{
    enzymeWrapper.find('button').simulate('click'); //click simulated
    expect(onContinueSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // working as expected
  });
});
```

Now how to spy **onSave** method.

Comment: I would recommend to test the side effect that is called inside `onSave`

Comment: is there any way to mock onSave.

Comment: Ah sorry, as `onSave` is a prop you can just pass the spy, will provide an anwser

Comment: what function is used for redirect? you need mock it to check if it has been called after click. the only challenge is async flow but Andreas Köberle has answered this below

Answer (score 0):

As `onSave` is a prop you can create a spy in your test and just pass it. Not that you call `.then` on the result of `onSave` call so you have to return a resolved promise.

```
describe('AddImage', () => {
 let onSave 
 let response
 beforeAll(() => {
    response = Promise.resolve()
    onSave = jest.fn(()=> response)
    const enzymeWrapper = ShallowRender(<AddImage {...props} onSave={onSave} />);

  });

  it('should continue and save image',async()=>{
    enzymeWrapper.find('button').simulate('click'); //click simulated
    expect(onSave).toHaveBeenCalledWith(); 
    await response // if you want to test the redirect you need to wait here
    // test the redirect here
  });
});
```

Comment: FAIL: Expected mock function to have been called. But not called.

Comment: Can you check what `this.props.onSave` is when you call it in your component.